# Are wizard bones tougher than human bones?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, muggles

In *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* we see the following dialogue:

> **Newt**: [hands Jacob a helmet] Put this on.
>   **Jacob**: But why would I have to wear something like this?
>   **Newt**: Because your skull is susceptible to breakage under immense force

Is Newt implying that his skull isn't (and wizard bones in general aren't) susceptible to breakage under immense force?

Or is it to be taken literally, and he is giving Jacob the protection he would normally use (and possibly is implying "Oh I'll be fine, but **you** need this").

Comment: I think it is implied that _anyone_ would be crushed if rammed by a Erumpent. Did you _see_ that thing?